For macOS flutter app Getting error 'APNS token has not been set yet. Please ensure the APNS token is available by calling `getAPNSToken()`'
I'm building an app which works on for 5 platforms - android, iOS, macOS, windows & web.
Now, I'm at point where I need to implemeent push notification for above 5 platforms.
I'm using firebase_messaging plugin for push notification . it works on android and iOS but not working on macOS .
throws the error [firebase_messaging/apns-token-not-set] APNS token has not been set yet. Please ensure the APNS token is available by calling getAPNSToken() while trying to get fcm token .
I've setup the firebase following this.
Even I've initialized the the plugin carefully for all platforms which supports.

void main() async {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  if (kIsWeb ||
      (Platform.isAndroid ||
          Platform.isIOS ||
          Platform.isMacOS 
          )) {
    NotificationService.init(); // calling it here to get fcmToken for testing
  } 
 NotificationService.getFcmToken();

runApp(MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
    BlocProvider<NetworkBloc>(
        create: (_) => NetworkBloc()..add(ListenConnection())),
    BlocProvider(create: (context) => SocketCubit()),
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => HomeCubit(),
    ),
    BlocProvider<ProfileCubit>(create: (_) => ProfileCubit()),
  ], 
  child: const MyApp()));
}

DefaultFirebaseOptions class :

class DefaultFirebaseOptions {
  static FirebaseOptions get currentPlatform {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return web;
    }
    switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return android;
    case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      return ios;
    case TargetPlatform.macOS:
      return macos;
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
      //  return windows;
      throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - '
              'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for linux - '
              'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      default:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions are not supported for this platform.',
        );
    }
  }

  static const FirebaseOptions web = FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "AIzaSy....",
      authDomain: "...",
      projectId: "...",
      storageBucket: "...",
      messagingSenderId: "......",
      appId: "...",
      measurementId: "..."
  );

  static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'AIz...',
    appId: '....',
    messagingSenderId: '....',
    projectId: '....',
    storageBucket: '....',
  );

static const FirebaseOptions ios = FirebaseOptions(
  apiKey: 'AIz....',
  appId: '....',
  messagingSenderId: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
);

static const FirebaseOptions macos = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: "AIz...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "....",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "....."
);
 
     
  
}


NotificationService class :
class NotificationService {
 static FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
 static init() async {
    await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    
  }

static Future<String?> getFcmToken() async {
    try {
      String? token;
      if (kIsWeb || Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS) {
        token = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      }
      // else if( Platform.isMacOS){
      //   await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
      //     token = await firebaseMessaging.getAPNSToken();

      // }
      else if (Platform.isWindows) {
        token = '';
      }

      debugPrint("FCM TOKEN--------------->$token");
      return token;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("FCM TOken error ----------->$e");
      rethrow;
    }
  }

}



On Firebase:

Goto Settings > Project Settings > General

Scroll down to find the iOS app

Add Team ID & App Store ID

GoTo Cloud Messaging Tab & make sure you've uploaded the authentication keys (p8 file). The same is generated from Developer Console > Keys.


Also, make sure you have added the Team ID & App Store ID as well.
On Xcode:

Enable Push Notification
Enable Background Modes & select Remote Notifications and Background fetch

I had faced the same issue on iOS and the authentication key(p8) file was missing & also the team IDs and App Store Ids were missing, adding which solved the problem for me.

I have already mentioned in my question,  for iOS device it works .
I want to implement push notification for macOS.
Please read the question .

I have uploaded the file(p8) ,  key and team to my firebase console already.
